# SQL - Priority Scenario

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Postgres table and I need to sort the data on below requirement

Case 1:

I have a table customer, which contains customers in queue & it has two types. Special (P) and Non special (E) customers, (P) - Special customer has high priority.

I need to sort the customers, as below three cases

```
Case-1: 

Source        Target
id Customer    id Customer
1 E            1 E
2 E            5 P
3 E            2 E 
4 E            6 P
5 P            3 E
6 P            4 E
```

In case-1, It has 4 (E) in row & then followed by 2 (P). So I need to place the (P) special customers in between 2  Non-special (E) customers.

```
Case-2: 

Source        Target
id Customer    id Customer
1 P            1 P
2 P            2 P
3 P            3 P 
4 E            4 E
5 E            7 P
6 E            5 E
7 P            6 E
8 E            8 E
9 E            9 E
```

In case-2, It has 3 (P) in row. So I need to place all 3 (P) in row. Because (P) is special customer. After that, same like case-1

```
Case-3: 

Source        Target
id Customer    id Customer
1 E            1 E
2 P            2 P
3 P            3 P 
4 P            4 P
5 E            5 E
6 E            6 P
7 E            7 E
8 P            8 E
```

In case-3, its like combination of Case-1 & Case-2. I need a single query, to fulfill all the above cases.

I tried something like rownumber & separating the customers & doing Union. But not working.

Comment: Provide some `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements to setup a sample data model and show the desired result. That makes it *much* easier to understand and answer the question.